# Uninstall Custom Item Template in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I have followed a few online tutorials and managed to install custom item templates using Visual Studio 2008.

Is it possible to uninstall my custom templates.  I've created several templates while trying to understand this and I don't want a few of these templates any more.

I've checked the registry, the Common 7\IDE... folders for the zip files, but I'm not sure how to uninstall the templates.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The templates are typically installed in your "My Documents" folder, on a windows XP Machine.

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Username\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Templates
```

On Vista

```
C:\Users\Username\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Templates
```

In here they are subdivided by the type of template.  (Item vs. Project) then from there the language.  Simply find and remove the .zip for the one you want to remove.